# PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc Assistance Please

Tags: php, arrays, database, while-loop

This may have been asked and answered already but I could not find a solution that works for what I am trying to do. I need to determine the end of an associative array created by mysqli_fetch_assoc($result). The code I have is:

```
$query = "SELECT * " .
         "FROM songs;";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$number = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    if($number !== 0){
        echo "{'title':'" .$row['song_name'] .
             "'file':'" . $row['song_path'] . "'},<br /><br />"; 
    } else {
        echo "{'title':'" .$row['song_name'] .
             "','file':'" . $row['song_path'] . "'}<br /><br />"; 
    }
    $number--;


}
```

Someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. What I want to do is echo the first part of the "if" statement and if the row is the last in the array I want to echo the else "without the comma at the end before the two break tags. It is returning all of the rows in the database but I just can't get rid of the comma if it is the end of the array. I am having a whale of a time with this. I know this might be easy stuff but I am new to PHP and it is throwing me for a loop. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Can you Try this,

```
  $i=1;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){    
        $comma =",";    
        if($i==$number){
            $comma ="";
        }   
        echo "{'title':'" .$row['song_name'] .
        "'file':'" . $row['song_path'] . "'}".$comma."<br /><br />";
        $i++;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
 ... 
 if($number > 1){
 ...
```

Or you can do it as

```
  ...
  $json = '';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

      $json .=  "{'title':'" .$row['song_name'] .
         "'file':'" . $row['song_path'] . "'},"; 
  }

  if(strlen($json) > 0)
       $json = substr($json,0, strlen($json)-1);

  echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0):

You use $number-- after one row is over so $number will be equal to 0 after all rows have been processed. So all you need to do is put $number-- before all the if clause

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $number--;//move to here
     if($number !== 0){
         echo "{'title':'" .$row['song_name'] .
              "'file':'" . $row['song_path'] . "'},<br /><br />"; 
     } else {
         echo "{'title':'" .$row['song_name'] .
              "','file':'" . $row['song_path'] . "'}<br /><br />"; 
     }
     //$number--; moved up


  }
```

Now it should works!! :)